# Install specific Ruby version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, yum

How do I install a specific Ruby version (say 1.9.3-p194) using **YUM**?

E.g. `yum install ruby --version`?

Is such a thing possible using **YUM**?

Comment: I don't know much about yum, but independent of your package manager I'd recommend you to use a ruby version manager such as rvm or rbenv, which allows you to conveniently install different ruby versions (on different patch levels if needed) in parallel.

Comment: If you want to manage multiple Ruby versions I'd recommend using something like [Ruby Version Manager (rvm)](http://rvm.io/).

Comment: Although this is a question about to use an OS package manager, I think it should be allowed under the usual exemption for programming tools, since it asks how to install a specific version of Ruby, something that a Ruby programmer will pretty commonly need to do.

Comment: Ruby is unnecessarily complex. Such a simple thing and I've been searching for this for half an hour because its not mentioned anywhere else.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend to use a ruby version manager like [rvm](https://rvm.io/) or [rbenv](http://rbenv.org/) instead of install a specific ruby version, it allows you to change, upgrade and install parallel versions with less effort.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with:

```
sudo yum install ruby-1.9.3
```

And just specify the version that you are interested in and is available in the yum repository.

Comment: How can i view all ruby versions in yum?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151689/how-can-i-instruct-yum-to-install-a-specific-version-of-package-x